# Free and paid app BlackBerry Playbook Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, blackberry-playbook

I've ported my paid Android app(recorder) to Blackberry PlayBook and, now I want to create the free version so I've copied and pasted the project, changed the package name, did my changes in the code but when I launch the app the paid version is deleted.

It keeps only one version, how can I maintain both versions? Probably in this way, if a user buys the paid app the current recordings in free version will be deleted.

Comment: For example paid is named Recorder and the free versione: Recorder Free and packages are com.example.recorder the first and com.example.recorderfree the second

Comment: Are your package names different in the first 25 or 29 characters?

Comment: No, are the same, now I try to change
Edit: Nothing has changed, Now I try to do a new project

Comment: Also with a new project one version replace the other..

Comment: I've resolved, since I've created them on the top of the original android app used like library in both Playbook version I had the same package name in the android manifest of original app.
I changed it and now one version doesn't replace the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved, since I've created them on the top of the original android app used like library in both Playbook version I had the same package name in the android manifest of original app. I changed it and now one version doesn't replace the other.